# Object won't move

Tags: html, css

I have two menus and I would like them both to be centered. The "portfolio" menu only appears on my portfolio pages so I would like the "menubar" menu to be beneath it but have them both centered. The "menubar" menu won't move at all no matter how I change the margins. What's going on?

I'm new to web design and so is my professor so I apologize for the badness of my code haha. Also if there's an easy way to center the rest of the text

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Connor Lepert: Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="logo.png">
    <style>
        @font-face {font-family: Vanadine; src: url(vanadine.ttf);}

        a {color: white; font-family: Vanadine; text-decoration: none;}
            a:hover {color: yellow;}
        p {color: white; font-family: Vanadine;}
        footer {font-family: sans-serif; margin-left: 45%; margin-right:45%;}
        body {color: white; background-color: #ABADB0}

        #siteid
        #menubar {position: absolute; margin-left: 400px; text-align: center; font-family: Vanadine;}
        #mediaicons {margin-left: 44.5%;}
        #portfolio {margin-left: 30%; margin-right: 30%}
        #header
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>
    <div id="portfolio">
        <a href="portfolio.html">Graphic Design</a>
        <a href="photovideo.html">Photography & Videography</a>
        <a href="music.html">Music</a>
    </div>
    </h1>

    <div id="menubar">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="aboutme.html">About</a>
        <a href=>Contact</a>
        <a href="resume.html">Resume</a>
        <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
        <a href="scrapyard.html">ScrapYard</a>
    </div>

    <div id="mediaicons">
    <a href=""><img src="instagram.png" width="30px"></a>
    <a href=""><img src="tumblr.png" width="30px"></a>
    <a href=""><img src="youtube.png" width="30px"></a>
    <a href=""><img src="soundcloud.png" width="30px"></a>
    </div>

    <object data="infographic.pdf" type="pdf" width="100%" height="1000px">
    <p>
        It appears you do not have a pdf plugin for this browser. Download the pdf <a href="infographic.pdf">here</a>.
    </p>
    </object>

    <object data="pagelayout.pdf" type="pdf" width="100%" height="1000px">
    <p>
        It appears you do not have a pdf plugin for this browser. Download the pdf <a href="pagelayout.pdf">here</a>.
    </p>
    </object>

    <br>

    <footer>©<a href=> 2015 by Connor Lepert </a></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have several run-on sentences, and your question is very hard to read. If you're new to HTML, then you should try to solve one part of your problem (e.g. mane menu only) first, then try adding more parts.

Comment: The title of this question should perhaps be changed… there’s nothing that should actually _move around_ (as in being animated), right…?

Answer (score 0):

Set the left/right margins to auto:

```
#portfolio { margin: 0 auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your style tag

```
<style>
    @font-face {font-family: Vanadine; src: url(vanadine.ttf);}

    a {color: white; font-family: Vanadine; text-decoration: none;}
        a:hover {color: yellow;}
    p {color: white; font-family: Vanadine;}
    footer {font-family: sans-serif; margin-left: 45%; margin-right:45%;}
    body {color: white; background-color: #ABADB0}

    #siteid
    #menubar {position: absolute; margin-left: 400px; text-align: center; font-family: Vanadine;}
    #mediaicons {margin-left: 44.5%;}
    #portfolio {margin-left: 30%; margin-right: 30%}
    #header
</style>
```

Please remove the #siteid under the body rules and the #header under the portfolio rules as this would cause a css error and the set of css rules after the rules for the body would be ignored

It would become this

```
<style>
    @font-face {font-family: Vanadine; src: url(vanadine.ttf);}

    a {color: white; font-family: Vanadine; text-decoration: none;}
        a:hover {color: yellow;}
    p {color: white; font-family: Vanadine;}
    footer {font-family: sans-serif; margin-left: 45%; margin-right:45%;}
    body {color: white; background-color: #ABADB0}

    /**#siteid removed **/
    #menubar {position: absolute; margin-left: 400px; text-align: center; font-family: Vanadine;}
    #mediaicons {margin-left: 44.5%;}
    #portfolio {margin-left: 30%; margin-right: 30%}
    /**#header removed **/
</style>
```

After that you need to change the css rules for #menubar and #portfolio

Replace them with

```
    #menubar {margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center; font-family: Vanadine;}
```

And

```
    #portfolio {margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
```

Everything finally becomes

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Connor Lepert: Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="logo.png">
    <style>
        @font-face {font-family: Vanadine; src: url(vanadine.ttf);}

        a {color: white; font-family: Vanadine; text-decoration: none;}
            a:hover {color: yellow;}
        p {color: white; font-family: Vanadine;}
        footer {font-family: sans-serif; margin-left: 45%; margin-right:45%;}
        body {color: white; background-color: #ABADB0}

        /**#siteid removed **/
        #menubar {margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center; font-family: Vanadine;}
        #mediaicons {margin-left: 44.5%;}
        #portfolio {margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
        /**#header removed **/
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>
    <div id="portfolio">
        <a href="portfolio.html">Graphic Design</a>
        <a href="photovideo.html">Photography & Videography</a>
        <a href="music.html">Music</a>
    </div>
    </h1>

    <div id="menubar">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="aboutme.html">About</a>
        <a href=>Contact</a>
        <a href="resume.html">Resume</a>
        <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
        <a href="scrapyard.html">ScrapYard</a>
    </div>

    <div id="mediaicons">
    <a href=""><img src="instagram.png" width="30px"></a>
    <a href=""><img src="tumblr.png" width="30px"></a>
    <a href=""><img src="youtube.png" width="30px"></a>
    <a href=""><img src="soundcloud.png" width="30px"></a>
    </div>

    <object data="infographic.pdf" type="pdf" width="100%" height="1000px">
    <p>
        It appears you do not have a pdf plugin for this browser. Download the pdf <a href="infographic.pdf">here</a>.
    </p>
    </object>

    <object data="pagelayout.pdf" type="pdf" width="100%" height="1000px">
    <p>
        It appears you do not have a pdf plugin for this browser. Download the pdf <a href="pagelayout.pdf">here</a>.
    </p>
    </object>

    <br>

    <footer>©<a href=> 2015 by Connor Lepert </a></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: margin-left:auto when used with margin-right:auto centralizes a blocked content.
Also Avoid using percentaged values.